# Is there a way to avoid reading specific bytes through PySerial, basically skipping them?

Tags: python, pyserial

I have data in the form of 33 bytes. Of the 33, only bytes 1-26 and 29-33 are of use to me. Currently, I am also reading 27 and 28 and storing them into nothing. Is there a way by which I needn't read them in the first place?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using.

Comment: You could do three separate `.read()` calls, with sizes 26, 2, and 5 respectively, and simply not do anything with the result of the middle call.  But two excess bytes is hardly worth worrying about - it would probably be clearer, and more efficient, to just read the whole thing in a single call and simply never do anything with those two bytes.